# How to mathematically prove the "transitive property of nested predictors"?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, data-analysis, combinatorial-designs, data-structure

Note: I posted this question on the Stats.Stackexchange site a week ago, but I think it might be better here. It's about proving a theorem I came up with about experiment data set structures, specifically nested predictors...

**QUESTION**

I am studying the structure of experiment data sets, and I want to propose a rule that I call the "transitive property of nested predictors".

The general idea is that…

- if there are three predictors: A, B, and C
- and if B is nested within A
- and if C is nested within B

Then…

- C is nested within A

My question is:

How can I prove that this rule is always true, using either mathematics, symbolic logic, set theory, diagrams, or something else? (See Example 1, below)

or

How can I prove that it is impossible to violate this rule? (See Example 2, below)

---

***Example 1***

An example data set that agrees with the proposed rule given above is shown here.

The dataset is:
[image]

A text description of this data set is:

[image]

And a graphical diagram of this data set is:

[image]

---

***Example 2***

An example experiment diagram that disagrees with the proposed rule is shown here, but I claim that such a data set does not exist.

[image]

---

**EDIT: DEFINITION OF NESTED PREDICTOR**

I define "nested" only in terms of the structure of the data set itself, not from any real-world situations. This is because the real world situations are irrelevant, as long as the levels of the nested predictors are coded properly, i.e. with unique level IDs.

> A categorical predictor is nested when each of its levels has a
> measurement in only one level of another categorical predictor, and
> there are at least two of its levels measured in each level of the
> other predictor.

This can be determined algorithmically or visually. Take the example data set shown here:

[image]

***Algorithmically***

[image]

***Visually***

[image]